# How to check if a polynomial map surjects onto a given zero locus

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I have a polynomial map $f:\mathbb{Z}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}^r$ (i.e. $f$ is given by $r$ polynomials, each polynomial in $n$ variables and with integer coefficients).

I also have finite sets $L\subset\mathbb{Z}[T_1,\dotsc,T_n]$ and $S\subset\mathbb{Z}[X_1,\dotsc,X_r]$. Let $X\subset\mathbb{Z}^n$ be the set of common zeros of $L$ and $Y\subset\mathbb{Z}^r$ the set of common zeros of $S$.

Assume that $f(X)\subset Y$. Is there an effective way to check if $f(X)=Y$?

Comment: It is unclear whether $\forall x\in  R^r\; (x\in Y\iff \forall g\in S \;(g(x)=0))$  
 OR $ \forall x\in R^r\;(x\in Y\iff \exists g\in S\;(g(x)=0)).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: I meant *common* zeros. I edited the question to say this.